# WaitCursor not Deactivating?

Tags: vb.net, cursor

My application has several forms and routines and in several of them I utilize "Application.UseWaitCursor = true".

The program functions corrctly but in some situations the cursor is not restored to Normal with "Application.UseWaitCursor = false".  I tried some additional methods as "Me.UseWaitCursor = false", "Me.Cursor = Cursors.Default", etc. but the application seems to be locked with the WaitCursor.

Do you know what can be happen?

See that simple task where this happens:

```
 Application.UseWaitCursor = true

 Dim Resposta as Boolean = Routine_to_Verify_Account()
 if Resposta = True
    X = "OK"
 else
    X = "There are some problems related to your account..."
 End If

 Application.UseWaitCursor = false
 Application.DoEvents()
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Never use Application.DoEvents: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jfoscoding/archive/2005/08/06/448560.aspx

Comment: Hmmm...  Thanks a lot for that explanation (even outside the main problem). I had never heard it before about DoEvents; thanks!